# Why is the plugin list so short?

Tags: qgis, plugins

i have installed QGIS with GRASS and QDAL complete...

I followed the instructions for additional QDAL configuration (adding usr/bin to the QDAL path).

When i try to "fetch plugins" my list is short and does not include geocoding.

I have downloaded a plugin from the main repository but it sits on my desktop undetected by QGIS

How do i access these plugins?

Answer (score 8):

Add

```
http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml
```

to the list of repositories in plugin installer 2nd tab. (If it should be missing.)

In Options tab, check if you have selected one of the "Show all plugins ..." options.

You can also add a lot of 3rd party plugins automatically to get a really long plugin list.